# Regarding a question in complex analysis related to poles

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

While trying exercises in complex analysis from assignment I am unable to think about a problem ->

> Problem is - If difference of two rational functions has no poles then prove that it is constant.

I tried taking Function 1 - Function 2 as f(z) / g(z) - p(z) /q(z) and it has no poles then g(z) = q(z) = 1 and F1 - F2 becomes f(z) - p(z) but I am unable to think what to do next!!

Please help

Comment: $z-z^2$ is the difference of rational functions without poles, but not constant.

Comment: As functions on the Riemann sphere, it has a pole at $z=\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the difference of your rational functions as
$$
f(z)=\frac{p(z)}{q(z)}
$$
where $p,q$ are polynomials. Then either $q$ has a complex root, in which case this is a pole of $f$, or $f$ is a polynomial. In the latter case, if $f$ is non-constant then it blows up to $\infty$ as $z\to\infty$ so we can consider $z=\infty$ as a pole of $f$. Consequently, if there is no pole (in this extended sense) then $f$ is constant.

More generally, if $X$ is a compact Riemann surface, then the only holomorphic functions $f\colon X\to\mathbb C$ are the constant functions - this is essentially [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)). We are considering the special case when $X$ is the Riemann sphere and $f$ is a rational function. In general rational functions on the Riemann sphere are meromorphic but not holomorphic. Or in other words, they are complex analytic maps from the Riemann sphere to itself, but not from the Riemann sphere to the complex plane $\mathbb C$.